# PysimpleGUI: How to keep a progress meter open, when max_value is reached?

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

A simple ProgressMeter from PySimpleGui is used to run through a list of files:

```
sg_gui.OneLineProgressMeter("Actual:", act_number, total_number, '_M_', actual_Filename)
```

How to keep the window open, after max_value = total_number is reached?

**MORE EXPLANTION**: My problem is that the window does not stay open when the last file is processed but it's absolutely fine for the first ones; this is my code:

```
import time
file_count = 1
for scan_file in scan_files:
   analyze_file  = scan_file.name
   mod_gui.OneLineProgressMeter("Actual File:", file_count, files_count, '_M_', analyze_file)
   result_file = analyze(analyze_dir, analyze_file)                                                                                     
   time.sleep(2)
   file_count += 1
```

I have two files for processing:

- The first one has `file_count = 1`, meter is visible.
- After this is finalized, `file_count` raises = 2, meter disappears.

May be, I need to start with `file_count = 0` in the second line?

Answer (score 0):

The window for `one_line_progress_meter` will be closed if `current_value >= max_value`. Maybe you can build the progress meter window, finalize and update it by yourself if you have special requirement, delete it by method close when necessary.

A simple progress meter simulated by Text element.

```py
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue')

layout = [[sg.Text('', size=(50, 1), relief='sunken', font=('Courier', 11),
    text_color='yellow', background_color='black',key='TEXT')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
text = window['TEXT']
state = 0
while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    state = (state+1)%51
    text.update('█'*state)

window.close()
```